# Pointer to subscript -- strstr function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an exercise where I should implement the `strstr` function from the standard library. The implementation of `strstr` seems to work, however, while it points to 'B', from "Foo Bar Baz", it returns "Bar Baz". How could I change the returned subscript so that it only returns the first occurrence of "B" of  "Bar" in "Foo Bar Baz"?

From the manual:

> If needle is an empty string, haystack is returned; if needle occurs nowhere in haystack, NULL is returned; otherwise a pointer to the first character of the first occurrence of needle is returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find) 
{
  int i;
  int n;

  i = 0;
  n = 0;
  if (to_find == NULL || str == NULL)
    return str;
  if (to_find != NULL) 
  {
    while (str[i] != '\0' && to_find[n] != '\0') 
    {
      while (str[i] == to_find[n]) 
      {
        i++;
        n++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return str[i - n - 1];
  } 
  else
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
  char *largestring = "Foo Bar Baz";
  char *smallstring = "Bar";
  char *ptr;

  ptr = ft_strstr(largestring, smallstring);
  printf("%s", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @broman its for an exercise that I found online. Reproduce the behaviour of strstr described in the manual.

Comment: @broman could you explain that in more detail? This is what I found in the man: If needle is an empty string, haystack is returned; if needle occurs nowhere in haystack, NULL is returned; otherwise a pointer to the first character of the first occurrence of needle is returned.

Comment: @broman You're right thanks, returns the same output, guess I misinterpreted the man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mimic the standard `strstr` function, but that function does not do what you're asking for. It actually does return a pointer to the first occurrence of `str` in `to_find`. Your current approach is actually correct.

However, there is two bugs. One is this line in `ft_strstr`:

```
return str[i - n - 1];
```

that should be:

```
return &str[i - n - 1];
```

The other one is in `main`:

```
printf("%s", *ptr);
```

that should be

```
printf("%s", ptr);
```

Fix these two things and your code should work as it should.

> If needle is an empty string, haystack is returned; if needle occurs nowhere in haystack, NULL is returned; otherwise a pointer to the first character of the first occurrence of needle is returned.

The pointer will still always (unless it's a null pointer) point somewhere in the haystack. I think that's what's confusing you.

Maybe this code snippet will help you:

```
char *largestring = "Foo Bar Baz";
char *smallstring = "Bar";
char *ptr = strstr(largestring, smallstring);
int index = ptr - largestring;
```

The variable `index` will now contain the index of the first occurrence, in your case it will be 4. (Given that it was found. It's possibly undefined behavior otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in what you report is not what is returned, but what you do with it. But first you have some errors:

- `return str[i - n - 1];` should be `return &str[i - n - 1];`
- `printf("%s", *ptr);` should be `printf("%s", ptr);`
- You are returning the first argument if the second is `NULL`, you
  should explicity return `NULL` for failure, otherwise the caller will think a substring was found.
- You must check the return value is not `NULL` (not found) before you
  dereference it.

You can print the result, and, just the first character with

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
```